# Excluding everything but API package in Maven

Tags: java, maven

I have a Java project that contains three major parts:

- `net.code`
- `xyz.code`
- `xyz.code.api`

I want to create two Jars: one for everything, and one for only `xyz.code.api`. The second Jar must also include all the dependencies.

I have two profiles setup to do this. The first profile works, but the second doesn't exclude the packages.

```
<profile>
  <id>all</id>
  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/res</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>xyz.code.Main</mainClass>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
<profile>
  <id>api</id>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
              <shadedClassifierName>api</shadedClassifierName>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>**/net/code/*</exclude>
                <exclude>**/xyz/code/*</exclude>
              </excludes>
              <includes>
                <include>**/xyz/code/api/*</include>
              </includes>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```

Two Jars are created, yet they both contain everything in the project.

Comment: Separation of concerns. Create separate modules from it...Simplest and cleanest solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the jars share the same dependencies (and therefore can have the same pom), you can think about using the maven ejb plugin:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ejb-plugin/examples/generating-ejb-client.html

Otherwise, one should think about splitting the project into two modules because creating two artifacts from the same project is "anti-Maven". There are workarounds, but they are more complicated.